# addEventListener function is being executed when listener is declared

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code

```
function change (elem){
  if (x==1) elem.innerHTML = "1";
  else elem.innerHTML = "not 1";
}
var test = document.getElementById ("abc");
var x=1;

test.addEventListener ("click", change(test));
```

and the html looks like this

```
<body>
  <div id="abc">a div</div>
</body>
```

How do I prevent the function from being executed until the div element is clicked? Right now it just changes the innerHTML by itself and I want it to wait for the click listener.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being executed immediately because you're *calling* it immediately:

```
test.addEventListener ("click", change(test));
```

You need to pass a function, not the result of a function call:

```
test.addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    change(test);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function the following way, for example:

```
test.addEventListener ("click", function(){change(test)});
```

[Here is an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crw7135x/)

Answer (score 0):

```
test.addEventListener("click", function(){ change(this);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are immediately executing the function change() because of the parenthesis.

Another way to do what you are trying is to pass the function by reference and using `this` to get the element.

```
function change (){
  if (x==1) this.innerHTML = "1";
  else this.innerHTML = "not 1";
}
var test = document.getElementById ("abc");
var x=1;

test.addEventListener ("click", change);
```